# Unable to hover over element using Selenium Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I have an element defined like below:

```
def InspectElement():
    global element
    element = driver.switch_to.active_element
    print(element)
    return element
```

I am trying to hover over it like so:

```
def MoveMouse():
    print('MovingMouse')
    ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).perform()
    return
```

This doesn't work. I think I need to get the xpath of the element instead of just asking it to click the element itself? Could that be it? If so, is there a way to get the xpath of the element? Googling it only comes up with ways to search by xpath, but I want to return xpath as an attribute of the element. Is that possible? Or am I going about it the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the xpath of an element by going to Chrome -> Right click Element -> Inspect -> Right click HTML -> Copy -> Copy XPATH

I would solve it like this:

```
def inspectElementMoveMouse():
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/header/div/div[1]/a[2]/span')
    print('MovingMouse')
    ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element)
    element.perform()
```

Comment: I'm creating a tool that allows me to manipulate elements during runtime, so manually going to inspect element would not work. I need to find a way to get the xpath of the element through Python, or another way to hover and click on it.